# How do I get the currently playing song in Rhythmbox using Python

Tags: python, dbus, rhythmbox

Im using Ubuntu 12.04. I want to access Rhythymbox using Python .

This is how I've proceeded so far:

Ive gone through this site
https://live.gnome.org/RhythmboxPlugins/WritingGuide , but it gives details on how to write plugins , which Im not interested in right now. Ive gone through a few tutorials which tells me to do this.

```
import dbus
session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()

proxy_obj = session_bus.get_object(
'org.gnome.Rhythmbox', '/org/gnome/Rhythmbox/Player')
```

But I am getting the following error

```
DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Rhythmbox was not provided by any .service files.
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction of what I would like to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean by access? What *specifically* are you trying to do?

Comment: I would just like to get the name of the song being played.

Comment: maybe you could take a look at the im-status plugin in `/usr/lib/rhythmbox/plugins/im-status/im-status.py`, it takes the song's name and puts it in pidgin/empathy

Answer (score 3):

A workaround, used by [lyricsdownloader.py](http://code.google.com/p/lyricsdownloader/), is:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('rhythmbox-client --no-start --print-playing-format %tt')))
title, err = proc.communicate()
```

Note: This does not work with Ubuntu 11.10, which shipped without rhythmbox-client.

Comment: How do can you capture title as a str? when I `print title` I get `None` and the var tests as a NoneType...

Comment: that's fine, but notice  there can be a few songs with the same name but in different folders (e.g. they  were sung in different years, but they have the same names).  I tried with way for deleting playing song, but problem was that I can't figure out which song I should delete. (and regards to luck I could delete another song)

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful. https://github.com/aliva/rhythmbox-microblogger

It is a twitter plugin for RhythmBox. So instead of twitter and Gtk, you can just take the current song.

```
from gi.repository import RB
```

`RB.RhythmDBPropType.TITLE` will give enum which you can use to get the title.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you've encountered a bug in Rhythmbox DBus interface described on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/+bug/968994). Tracker says that fix is committed, but possibly your version doesn't have that fix.

Comment: It's still happening, long after "fix released"